# Mac - Zend Server CE and Zend Framework applications very very slow

Tags: macos, zend-framework, zend-server-ce

My company is using Zend Server CE on Macs for testing and developing our Zend Framework applications, these applications run very quickly on Linux and Windows test machines (0.2 - 1 second page loads) but on the Macs using Zend Server CE each page takes up to 2 minutes to load, making development and testing very time consuming.

We have tried turning off Zend Debug (Which defeats the purpose of using the product) and so on.

Has anyone else experienced this? Are there any tweaks to configs people can suggest to improve performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We changed all the Macs to XAMPP and now sites run, from this experience I would not recommend Zend Server CE on a Mac, something strange seems to be going on under the hood.